# Pretty format plugin: Range error: Invalid string length

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to render a component in a test using the render method from react testing library. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
RangeError: Invalid string length
```

I tried to render a simpler component (with just a div) and the error doesn't happen in that case.

Does anyone know how to fix that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of your snapshot.
For us it was the problem of including store and router into snapshot so the total number of lines exceeded 1M lines -> so Invalid string length error was thrown.

Looks like JSON stops working with such big payloads.